# How to change height of top row within a List?

Tags: list, custom-list

I would like to adjust the height of the top row (top bar?) within my lists - is this possible?

Some of my column titles are lengthy which creates a lot of empty space within the column, I want to tighten the List up as one could within Excel by adjusting heights and widths.  Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: check this if solve the problem: http://bkemmler.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-list-fixed-header.html or explain little bit, what you want just change the height and width of the header?